# How to call method of each object within an object

Tags: javascript, object, for-loop, coffeescript, iteration

I want to iterate the object `Items` inside of the object `player`. `Items` is a set of objects in which each of them have a method `add`. When I use this it throws an error saying that item is undefined. How can I call `add` on each item?

```
for item of player.Items
    player.Items.item.add()
```

P.S. I am using coffeescript

Comment: can you give a real example of the player object, what does add() method do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
player.Items[item].add();
```

Maybe this?
I don't know how cofeescript parse this (or work at all) so It's just a wild guess.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the loop incorrectly. I suggest you take a look at CoffeeScript's [documentation](http://coffeescript.org/#loops) to understand how for loops work in CS.

Depending whether player.Items is an Array or Object...

For Arrays:

```
# Loop through the individual elements in the Array, where
# each element is assigned to the item variable
item.add() for item in player.Items
```

For Objects:

```
# Loop through the Object's enumerable keys, assigning the key's name to key variable
# and the key's contents (another Object, I assume) to the item variable
item.add() for key,item of player.Items
```

Your code is using the Object iterator form but only specifies one variable where the for loop is expected to assign two pieces of information and so your `item` variable is just a string or a number ( depending on what player.Items actually is ).

Secondly, even if you defined the for loop correctly, your code would fail, because you are referencing a variable called `item` of `player.Items`. In case of Objects, You would have to either use `player.Items[key].add()`, `item.add()` or in case of Arrays simply `item.add()`.

Answer (score 0):

That isn't how for loops work in any language. The looping variable is referenced directly, not tacked onto the end of the collection. You're also using `of` incorrectly; if `Items` is an array, you need to use `for/in`:

```
for item in player.Items
   item.add()
```

You can write this as a simple array comprehension:

```
item.add() for item in player.Items
```

Lastly, there is a strong convention in CoffeeScript and JavaScript: You should only be using uppercase letters to denote *classes*, never variables. Your collection should be called `player.items`.

Comment: `Items` contains objects, so I should use `of` and when I change my code to yours it throws an error saying that the item has not method `add`.

Comment: If `Items` is an array, you need `in`. It doesn't matter what it is an array of, whether it's objects or nested arrays or strings or numbers. However, if `Items` is *itself* an object, and not an array, then use `of`: `item.add() for i,item of player.Items`